# Insert text from a Text Area in a MySQL DB (Python/Flask)

Tags: python, mysql, text, insert, message

I want to code a small message feed for my homepage. I want to send a text from a textarea to my Database
this is my html template:

```
 {% extends 'layout.html'%}

 {% block body%}

   <form action="/feed" method="post">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td><textarea name="feedtext" id="feedtext" placeholder="Type message here!" rows="4" cols="53"></textarea></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><button style="width: 65%;" "submit"\>Send</button></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   </form>

{% endblock %}
```

now my problem is the python part. I try anything but I don't get the right code.

this is my python code now:

```
 @app.route('/feed', methods=['POST'])
 def feed():
     try:
         conn = mysql.connect()
         cursor = conn.cursor()
         feedtxt = request.form['feedtext']

         cursor.execute('INSERT INTO nachrichten (Vorname, Nachname, Nachricht) VALUES(%);', (feedtxt))

     finally:
         cursor.close()
         conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Welcome**.

Can not make out "**I try anything but I don't get the right code**".

Anyway, out of the columns

> (Vorname, Nachname, Nachricht)

it seems only the Nachricht gets the value of (feedtxt).

Try giving 3 items within **VALUES**